# Echo protected content after login

Tags: php, security

#### What I try to achieve

I need to create a administration-panel for a website. Therefore, I need a possibility to protect the content of the panel via a password. The functionality doesn't have to be very advanced. I  neither need a password-reset functionality nor the possibility to add more than one user. I also don't need a "keep me logged in"-functionality.

It is also a pretty small site, so I don't think the security standards need to be as high as with big companies.

I can't use cookies for this project. It is for a completely "cookie-free" website.

#### Code

The basic code looks like this:

```php
<?php

//Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php
$username = '$2y$10$bWW0KD6P7WUaTU99PpcjtON1xKSBhCCxxiiyoaMuY0aVehZSfgVI6'; //result of password_hash("admin", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$password = '$2y$10$NxtrHFdZGZMG7y2G6l2o6eZpksOQfQvrQrCBTj7knEmL8VynQlcz2'; //result of password_hash("1234", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

//Loading login form
$content = "<h1>Login</h1>
            <form method='POST' class='input'>
                <label>
                    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' class='validInput' required/>
                </label>
            
                <label>
                    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' class='validInput' required/>
                </label>
            
                <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login'/>
            </form>";

//Check if form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    //Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php
    $verifyUsername = password_verify($_POST['username'], $username);
    $verifyPassword = password_verify($_POST['password'], $password);

    //Check if user entered correct username and password
    if($verifyUsername && $verifyPassword) {
        //Load protected content
        $content = "<h1>Welcome</h1><p>Content here!</p>";
    }

    //Reload login form
    else {
        $content = "<h1>Login</h1>
                    <p>Wrong username or password!</p>
                    <form method='POST' class='input'>
                        <label>
                            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' class='validInput' required/>
                        </label>
                    
                        <label>
                            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' class='validInput' required/>
                        </label>
                    
                        <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login'/>
                    </form>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>John Doe</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>
    <body id='body'>
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Questions

Is this a secure possibility for basic login? Is it secure to just echo the protected content once the user logged in? If not, what can I improve to make it secure? What else should I think of?

Is [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) a good and secure alternative for this task?

---

Edit in reply to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64863634/echo-protected-content-after-login#comment114679479_64863634) from Ro Achterberg:

- It is protecting a content management system. A potential attacker would be able to change, delete or replace content.
- It needs to keep out everyone apart from the website owner

Comment: To answer this somewhat objectively, you have to first define some design goals. Whether this is "secure" is far too broad a question. What kind of data is it protecting, what are the risks of having it leaked, corrupted or stolen? Who does it need to keep out? Answer these questions first and then you can perform a careful analysis of the available options. However, there isn't anything _wrong_ with your design, and it'll keep the protected content away from unauthenticated users. If that's all you need, then I say go for it.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I just updated my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: A little, but what I was getting at were the benefits of doing a more concrete risk assessment. How sensitive is the content you're managing? Who would have a potential interest in doing something unlawful with it? But from the looks of things, the data isn't very important, and you should be good. HTTP Basic Authentication is another way of protecting a page, but I kind of like the self-contained nature of your approach. You can drop it anywhere and it'll work, with zero-configuration.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Well, yes, the content isn't really sensitive.But I also don't want to wake up one day and someone deleted all my content or uploaded a html-file with malicious javascript in it. Nevertheless, I am here to learn about concrete steps to increase the security of this approach - not because it is a necessity to increase it, but just for learning purposes. Would HTTP authentication be a more secure approach, or is it equally good from a security perspective?

Comment: If you want to improve on the security, then the best way to do that is to add layers. For instance, you might consider using client certificates to authenticate the device you're on. Only if that is accepted, you can present your user (you) with a pass phrase. The strength of your password is important. If you want to go one step further, you might integrate a OTP (one time pass) via SMS or something similar. If you're accessing the CMS from a fixed location, then you can filter inbound network requests from unauthenticated origins. These are just some examples.